# How do we configure spring-boot-admin client with multiple ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have configured the admin and clients (using the spring cloud discovery option) successfully using the actuator endpoints having AVI urls. These AVI endpoints are configured with multiple instances however the admin UI always shows once instance and does not recognize other instances. How do I configure these instances? I tried with other option where client can configure themselves with the admin url but the admin fails to register them as separate instances and shows its own actuator endpoints data (admin is itself registered as client) with ip address as 0.0.0.0:443.

I have tried searching on other threads but not getting any clue. I may be missing something. Thanks in advance.